# One-on-One's at New Job, Is This Common?

Tags: meetings

I just started a new job a couple weeks ago. I just noticed that my boss scheduled some short weekly meetings with me for about the next five–seven week (or, how ever long they're needed).

Is this common practice with new employees or should I be concerned that I've done something to cause concern?

Comment: Yes, one on ones are a vital part of managing employees, new and not new.

Comment: When I started as a new worker, we had a weekly onboarding meeting for 8 weeks, where my manager asked about how everything regarding the work was going, and what I should do next, and have all the necessary things been given to me (laptop, logins, ID badges, etc). Then there was a list of things to do, like attend this internal training and so on. Nothing to worry about - it is probably a similar thing for you. It's quite helpful and useful.

Comment: I would be concerned if you're not willing to ask your new boss about the nature of the meetings and is there anything you need to do to be prepared.

Comment: I would be more worried if I ahd a boss who did not want to have these meetings espcially with somone new who is likely to have issues that need to be addressed to get him or her fully up to speed and whose intial performance needs to be monitored to make sure they are getting up to speed.

Comment: Since he scheduled more than one meeting, you can bet you have nothing to worry about. If you "did something wrong", why would he need more than one meeting to tell you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd likely wait until the first one before passing judgment here. A few reasons for these meetings:

1. Ensure a good start. The first couple of weeks are likely to be where someone is getting initially set up and so after that could be the time to check-in and see how things are going and make sure the next month or so is where things get done.
2. High Performance option. Perhaps you were identified as someone that may be put onto a track for management or leadership positions. Could be grooming being done in this case.
3. Performance Improvement Process. This is similarly to 1 except that there are some specific concerns to be worked over the next month and a half or so.

Answer (score 6):

I think that you are lucky to have a manager who chose to invest her/his time in one-on-one meetings. Use them to create a relationship with her/him, try to understand what her/his values are and how she/he works and these 1-o-1s could easily be an asset.

Comment: Nowhere in the question it states OP's boss is a male.

Answer (score 6):

> Is this common practice with new employees or should I be concerned
>   that I've done something to cause concern?

I always have weekly one-on-one meetings with individuals on my team. I do this for new employees as well as for employees that have been around for many years.

For me, it's a way to better connect with them individually, to make sure they are getting what they need to succeed, to hear what they want to say that isn't appropriate in a group setting, and to talk about how they are doing.

For newer employees, my focus may be more on how they are acclimating, adjusting, and coming up to speed. But that's normal for someone new, and nothing to worry about.

If one-on-ones are common in your company/department, then you certainly shouldn't be worried about yours.

If one-on-ones are common for new employees in your company/department, then you certainly shouldn't be worried about yours.

If one-on-ones are the exception, then don't worry. During your next one-on-one ask for feedback. You'll likely find you are worrying unnecessarily. Or, you'll find out what you need to do to stop worrying.

Answer (score 3):

Since I normally have a weekly one-on-one with my boss, I'd say that generically, no, they are not necessarily an indication that anything is amiss.

If no one else ever has one-on-ones with the boss, it might be a problem, but it also might not. Your boss might be trying to start doing one-on-ones with everyone and you just happen to be the first chosen for it.

Have patience in trying to figure it out and be grateful for the opportunity to communicate with and learn from your boss in this environment.